# Make div fit to screen after opening mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mini game which i created using javascript and html. I have added three screenshots in order:

1:How the game looks onload without the keyboard open

2:How the game looks when you click on the text box to open the keybaord (not how i want it to look(zoomed))

3:How i want the div to look. It zooms out once i double touch on the screen

When you click on the text box on mobile devices i want the div to zoom out and fit to screen so the user can see all of the game when they keyboard is open. Does anyone know how? Below is the css for the div and screenshots of the website

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zusti.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kmHZ.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7hv.png
[css]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtQMH.png
```

Comment: Hi there, for the css, please include it as formatted code rather than an image. For the other links, do checkout markdown syntax so that these display - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Answer (score 0):

include this in your html head tag which will prevent the auto zoom in on inputs being selected, not sure if this is exactly what you want but it may help

`meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0")`

Comment: This makes the div go to the bottom and zooms out the website, i want it so when you click the text box it does not zoom in to the div